# How to learn joomla 1.5?

Tags: joomla

I'm a web designer and so I learnt everything essential needed for designers and now I can design the websites using joomla.

But I want to move myself to programmer. I have very basic knowledge of php and mysql. I wanted to know how can I enter into development with joomla.

Joomla has been very popular in the world but also it has not implemented so much effort for the users. It is providing a tutorial but randomly, so I'm confused how to start. There is no any sites step by step tutorials for joomla.

So, anyone please help me how to start on the topics. Could anyone provide a lists what to learn as to become a developer of joomla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all, you need to know about the versions.

There are 2 types of Joomla releases. Long Term (Joomla 1.5 and 2.5) and Short Term (Joomla 3.x)

Joomla 1.5 is old and unsupported now so there is no need to look into it.

If you want to start developing for Joomla, then you simply need to read up on the [documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/) and start messing around with [pre-made extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org). You will also need to do research on how MVC works if you are not already familiar with it.

Hope this helps

Comment: Could you please lists the topics step by step.

Comment: It has already been done for you. Look at this for example, [how to develop a component](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component). Or [how to develop a module](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_simple_module). It is all there, just spend some time looking.

Comment: If you need to work on a site that has already been made using 1.5, then upgrade it to 2.5. There area lot of changes between 1.5 and 2.5, features and security being the mains things. There will be limitation when learning 2.5 and developing for 1.5. Please do some research yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you can get help from a nice book such as [Joomla! Programming](http://joomlaprogrammingbook.com/)